# Check if username exists - cross browser issues! Suggestions?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I've a registration form and it checks existing usernames and email addresses in the database dynamically. However, it doesn't seem to be working on either FireFox or IE. It's great on Safari and Chrome though. Here's the code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="registerinvitel" onKeyUp="resettooltip();" onFocusOut="check_register_exist('username');" autocomplete="off" />
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function check_register_exist(meth){
    var cueajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        cueajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            cueajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                cueajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    cueajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(cueajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
var cuerez = cueajaxRequest.responseText;

if ( cuerez == 'exist' ) { infotooltip(meth, cuerez); 

document.getElementById('chk'+meth).value = "exist";

} else { document.getElementById('chk'+meth).value = "ok"; }


        }
    }


    var curchk = document.getElementById(meth).value;
    var queryString = "meth="+meth+"&u=" + curchk;
    cuenocache = Math.random();
    cueajaxRequest.open("GET", "/ajax/check.php?" + queryString + "&nocache=" + cuenocache, true);
    cueajaxRequest.send(null); 


}
```

Any ideas how I can alter it to make it work? The AJAX check.php code is as follows (but I don't think that's the problem):

```
<?

include  "../conf/config.php";

if(isset($_GET['meth'])) { $meth = $_GET['meth']; } else { $meth = ''; }
if(isset($_GET['u'])) { $u = $_GET['u']; } else { $u = ''; }


if ( $meth == 'username' ) {


$query_chkuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username = '$u'");
$query_nr_res = mysql_num_rows($query_chkuser);

if ( $query_nr_res == '1' ) { echo "exist"; } else { echo "ok"; }


} 

elseif ( $meth == 'email' ) {


$query_chkuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Email = '$u'");
$query_nr_res = mysql_num_rows($query_chkuser);

if ( $query_nr_res == '1' ) { echo "exist"; } else { echo "ok"; }


} 

else {}
```

Comment: What happens? You need to provide more detail than saying it does not work. Do you know how to debug? Set break points, see where the code works or does not work.

Comment: It simply doesn't show up the tooltip saying there's an error and instead allows me to register a second account with the same username.

Comment: Does your function get called, do you see an Ajax request go out? You need to figure out where it is broken.

Comment: There's an SQL injection hole in `check.php`. Use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) instead. And you need to use `encodeURIComponent` on all query string parameters.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino Agreed. I feel the same way about the obtrusive javascript as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `onBlur` instead of `onFocusOut`.

EDIT: Or, even better, `onChange` - after all, you don't need to recheck if the user hasn't changed the text.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Can't believe it was that obvious. Been working to try and resolve it for about an hour. Phew! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: but here because its ajax request `onBlur` is better because of not wasting bandwidth

Comment: @imsiso Um, why? Surely it's better to use `onChange` to prevent wasted bandwidth?

Comment: @imsiso You're thinking the exact opposite. Blurring the textbox doesn't mean the value changed - it *might*. But why would you take the risk when you can know for sure with `onchange`? Why would you want to send the request if the value didn't even change?

Comment: I mean we need the function to be called when we do the change I mean finish the change not 10 times while typing and making the change I don't know if I'm wrong plz tell me.

Comment: @Ian - you are right +1.OK what about a combination of them I mean lets set a `flag=true` `onchange` and call the function `onBlur` if only the `flag=true` and then set the `flag=false`

Comment: @imsiso If you set it up properly, something like that could work. But my point is why bother? When there's an event, `onchange`, that does that for you, completely reliably, and works across browsers

Comment: @Ian I want to say we want to check for example if user `fooboo` is exists why we should also check 'f', 'fo', 'foo',...? I want to say I think its better to use a combination of on change and timer/onBlure to improve the performance and avoid wasting bandwidth what do you think?

Comment: @imsiso `onChange` only fires when the field loses focus, and even then only if the value was changed since it received focus.

Comment: @imsiso No problem. I think you were thinking of the `keyup` event maybe? I think you had the right idea - don't send the request when it's not necessary; you were just thinking of the wrong event type